# Double chevron instead of guillemets

Tags: font-encodings

Here's a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\texttt{>>}
\end{document}
```

This makes a right guillemet. I'd like a double chevron. If I comment out the fontenc package, I indeed get a double chevron. Any advice?

Comment: With T1 fontend you should get a right guillemet, but without it you shouldn't be getting a double chevron; are you sure you haven't left something out?

Comment: A "chevron" is an upside-down v - are you sure that's what you mean? Or do you just mean a "greater-than" symbol?

Comment: I mean the "greater-than" symbol.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can break up the two `>` symbols by putting `{}` between them, like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\texttt{>{}>}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Works for me, but I find it annoying to have to do it every time...

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `microtype` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}

%% disable the << and >> ligatures in typewriter type
\DisableLigatures[<,>]{encoding=T1,family=tt*}

\begin{document}
\texttt{<<abc>>}

<<abc>>
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works, but it changes the font of the whole document.

Comment: @Andreina In what sense?

Comment: to be honest, it was imperceptible to the naked eye, but I think it was only changing the spacing.  Anyway, I managed to fix it by adding this: 

\usepackage[protrusion=false,expansion=false]{microtype} 

Either it's a normal problem or it happened because I'm using the lncs style.